# Mock constructor value in JUnit test

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have the following controller which I want to test:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/account")
public class AccountController {

    private final AccountService accountService;

    private UUID correspondentId;


    public AccountController(AccountService accountService, @Value("${app.correspondent}") String correspondentId) {
        this.accountService = accountService;
        this.correspondentId = UUID.fromString(correspondentId);
    }

    @GetMapping("")
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('CUSTOMER')")
    Mono<String> index(Authentication auth) {
        return.....;
    }
```

I tried to mock a test this way:

```
@Test
public void testMockUser() {
        AccountService accountService = Mockito.mock(AccountService.class);
        Mockito.mock(AccountController.class, withSettings().useConstructor(accountService, 
        UUID.randomUUID()));

        webTestClient
                .mutateWith(jwtMutator())
                .get().uri("/api/account/")
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .exchange()
                .expectStatus().isOk();
}
```

But I get error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid UUID string:
```

Do you know what is the proper way to mock the constructor value?

Comment: can u add complete test class ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem might be related to creating the bean itself and not the mock (probably it resolves `@Value("${app.correspondent}")` to `""` in the test environment and then fails as it's not an UUID. I suggest putting something like `app.correspondent=d7aa282f-a8aa-40f9-bce6-08ce6737b6e1` in the properties and check it out.

Also, it looks like there's another problem you might face: it's `AccountService, String` method signature in the controller and `AccountService, UUID` in the mock. Pretty sure this will give another error with mock construction. Though, this is easy to fix with a simple toString.

Comment: I can't edit properties file. Some other solution?

Comment: You may do something like that: `@SpringBootTest(properties = { "app.correspondent=d7aa282f-a8aa-40f9-bce6-08ce6737b6e1" })`

Comment: Note: if you absolutely need the randomization, you can also use SPEL, though this would look a bit weird: `@SpringBootTest(properties = { "app.correspondent=#{T(java.util.UUID).randomUUID().toString()}" })`

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you use Spring then in `application-test.properties` you could add

```yaml
app.correspondent=some-value
```

And in test class you use `@MockBean` as:

```java
class TestClass {
  @MockBean
  private AccountService accountService;

}
```

At context start-up Spring will create `AccountController` with the value injected from `application-test.properties` and mocked `accountService`.